# Azure Logic Apps- Securing Manual Http Trigger

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there a method to secure a Manual Http Trigger in a logic App with Basic Authentication.

Is this achieved through APi Management.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication mechanism used by Logic Apps is based on SAS keys that only a user with management access to the resource can list. In case any of the keys are exposed, you can use the /regenerateAccessKey operation on the logic app. See [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-http-endpoint/#adding-a-trigger-to-your-definition) for details.

In addition there is a capability to restrict firing a logic app if not coming from a specific range of IP addresses. This is not yet surfaced in the azure portal (as of 2016-11-09), but could be done manually via PowerShell and/or the management APIs.

For any other authentication mechanisms you would indeed want to use API Management as a frontdoor to your logic apps.

Comment: Hi,yes I have added my APi to API Management and applied a Policy using Basic Authentication, but this does not seem to have any effect when I post a request via Postman with Authentication headers added.

Comment: Are you invoking the logic app through the API Management endpoint, or are you still attempting to invoke it directly?